# Linear drag for pendulum in air, justifiable or not?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, drag

So, when trying to [measure the gravity constant $g$ at home](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/721748/71413)  through a pendulum I realized I wanted to try to model drag on the pendulum, to get a more accurate result.

I am asking how we can justify linear drag because that is the only **easily** solved model [and that seems to be what people in literature](http://dx.doi.org/10.4236/jamp.2017.51013) and here [on phys.stack](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/293835/71413) do, but I don't understand why it should work.

Assuming $F_{drag}\propto v$ is equivalent to assuming a low Reynolds number right? They argue this in the linked paper, claiming $ R_e\approx 1200$ would be low enough.

[From Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#The_drag_equation) (horrifyingly they actually quote wiki in this paper but that's another discussion)

> At low $R_{e}, C_{D} $is asymptotically proportional to ${\displaystyle R_{e}^{-1}} $, which means that the drag is linearly proportional to the speed, [...] given by the Stokes Law

But I have done several derivations of Stokes law myself  and you really need to assume a very viscous environment, basically you can derive it, if almost all inertia can be neglected (like for a bacterium in water, Kundu cites mist drops, or molten plastic in this regime). Which certainly not the case for a pendulum.

To show a source on what low $R_e$ means, [from the same wiki article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#Very_low_Reynolds_numbers:_Stokes%27_drag):

> [...] (i.e. low Reynolds number, ${\displaystyle R_{e}<1}).$ [...] The equation for viscous resistance is:
> $ \mathbf{F}_d = - b \mathbf{v}$

Kundu gives an upper limit of $R_e < 5$ for the validity of this approximation.

I am no expert but i am pretty sure that these Reynolds numbers are too low for my pendulum.

**Concluding:** Can anybody either help me justify linear drag in a more sensible way or put the notion of realistic linear drag for a pendulum in air to bed in a more rigorous way once and for all?

Comment: Why not plot a graph of (ln) amplitude of pendulum vs oscillation number to get an estimate of the effect of drag? Such experiments are well documented on the Internet and [here is one which automates taking data readings](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2002/2002.03796.pdf).

Comment: The link you provided quotes the paper that I linked above as a source of authority for using linear drag even quoting Re ~1200 which according to their own source (Wikipedia apparently...) is not even the right number and way too high. This lack of rigor in this context is the reason for my question.

Comment: @Farcher You will just see damped oscillations which will be cumulative effect of drag force **AND** friction in pivot / kinetic energy thermal looses. The question is,- How to extract only drag effect from a cumulative one (because you can't have friction-less pivot point) ?